# fetching number of records from outer join table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - band and comments. Comments table holds record if any comment has been made on a specific band in the band table. I need number of comments made on a band with all the details from band table. So here is my query

```
select band.*, count(comments.band) as count  from band left join comments on band.id = comments.band
```

However this query fetches only records that matches both the table. I need all the band table records to be listed even if there is no matching record for it in the comments table (main reason for using left join) Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it will work perfectly-

```
SELECT 
    band.*, COUNT(comments.band) AS count_no
FROM
    band
        LEFT JOIN
    comments ON band.id = comments.band
GROUP BY band.id;
```

Comment: Hey .. Thanks for the help. It worked. Could you pls let me know how the group by is making the difference?

Comment: If you are using aggregate functions like count then it will show only  one result.If you want to get result like above one you should use group by. Group by specially grouped result depending on your group by parameter. If you use aggregate function and get result depending on any field then use group by with that field. For your better convenience you can see this example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm

Answer (score 2):

SQLfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/986c8/6

```
SELECT b.name, count(c.band_id) AS comment_count
FROM band AS b
LEFT JOIN comments AS c
ON b.id = c.band_id
GROUP BY b.name;
```

EDIT: Looks like some people beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

That query looks correct to me except you don't have a `GROUP BY` clause. Without a `GROUP BY` it will only return 1 row with the count for all rows in it. You can use the band tables primary key. ie `GROUP BY band.id`